# Android:achartengine - XYChart overlap axis while zooming

Tags: android, achartengine

I am charting using AChartEngine in a linearlayout.
I have a margins for chart

```
      mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] {20, 50, 20, 20});
```

The problem is when I the zoom chart, it overlaps the axis.
How to fix that? Why do margins not work when I zoom the chart?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.
The problem is in this piece of code

```
mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01));
```

I set Margins color to transperent, because I want my background view to be visible.
So the solution is to paint Margins.
The solution is not perfect, but its works for me.